# org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property - mapping issue

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am posting this question because all the other questions with the same title was not able to resolve my issue.

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE CONTRACT_DB_AGREEMENT (
    AGREEMENT_CODE          VARCHAR2(50),
    COM_CONTRACT_CODE       VARCHAR2(15),
    AGREEMENT_TYPE          VARCHAR2(20),
    EXPIRE_DATE             TIMESTAMP(6),
    SIGNATORY_USER_NAME     NVARCHAR2(150),
    SIGNATORY_NAME          NVARCHAR2(50),
    ORIGINATOR_USER_NAME    NVARCHAR2(150),
    ORIGINATOR_NAME         NVARCHAR2(50),
    DATE_CREATED            TIMESTAMP(6),
    CREATED_BY              NVARCHAR2(150),
    LAST_UPDATE_DATE        TIMESTAMP(6),
    LAST_UPDATED_BY         NVARCHAR2(150),
    CONSTRAINT CONTRACT_DB_AGREEMENT_PK PRIMARY KEY (AGREEMENT_CODE),
    CONSTRAINT CONTRACT_DB_AGREEMENT_FK1 FOREIGN KEY(COM_CONTRACT_CODE) REFERENCES CONTRACTS (CONTRACT_CODE)
);
```

In the HBM file, I have this:

```
<id name="agreementCode" type="string">
    <column name="AGREEMENT_CODE" length="50" />
    <generator class="assigned" />
</id>

<property name="agreementType" type="string">
    <meta attribute="scope-field">@Length(min = 0, max = 20) private</meta>
    <column name="AGREEMENT_TYPE" length="20" />
</property>     
<property name="expireDate" type="timestamp">
    <column name="EXPIRE_DATE" sql-type="timestamp" />
</property>
<property name="signatoryUserName" type="string">
    <meta attribute="scope-field">@Length(min=0, max=150) private</meta>
    <column name="SIGNATORY_USER_NAME" length="150" />
</property>
<property name="signatoryName" type="string">
    <meta attribute="scope-field">@Length(min=0, max=50) private</meta>
    <column name="SIGNATORY_NAME" length="50" />
</property>
<property name="originatorUserName" type="string">
    <meta attribute="scope-field">@Length(min=0, max=150) private</meta>
    <column name="ORIGINATOR_USER_NAME" length="150" />
</property>
<property name="originatorName" type="string">
    <meta attribute="scope-field">@Length(min=0, max=50) private</meta>
    <column name="ORIGINATOR_NAME" length="50" />
</property>
<property name="dateCreated" type="timestamp">
    <column name="DATE_CREATED" sql-type="timestamp" />
</property>
<property name="createdBy" type="string">
    <meta attribute="scope-field">@Length(min=0, max=150) private</meta>
    <column name="CREATED_BY" length="150" />
</property>
<property name="lastUpdateDate" type="timestamp">
    <column name="LAST_UPDATE_DATE" sql-type="timestamp" />
</property>
<property name="lastUpdatedBy" type="string">
    <meta attribute="scope-field">@Length(min=0, max=150) private</meta>
    <column name="LAST_UPDATED_BY" length="150" />
</property>

<set name="contractDBAttachments" inverse="true" cascade="save-update">
    <key>
        <column name="AGREEMENT_CODE" />
    </key>
    <one-to-many class="ContractDBAttachment" />
</set>
<set name="contractDBNotes" inverse="true" cascade="save-update">
    <key>
        <column name="AGREEMENT_CODE" />
    </key>
    <one-to-many class="ContractDBNote" />
</set>

<many-to-one name="contract" class="Contract">
    <meta attribute="scope-field">@Length(min = 0, max = 15) private</meta>
    <column name="COM_CONTRACT_CODE" length="15"/>
</many-to-one>
```

I try to run this HQL:

```
String sql = "SELECT a FROM ContractDBAgreement a WHERE a.comContractCode = ?";
params.add(contractCode);

List<ContractDBAgreement> resultList = DaoManager.getDao(ContractDBAgreement.class).searchBySql(sql, params.toArray());
```

But I get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: comContractCode of: com.company.entity.ContractDBAgreement [SELECT a FROM com.company.entity.ContractDBAgreement a WHERE a.comContractCode = ?]
```

I appreciate any help on this please. Thank you!

**UPDATE/EDIT**

I updated the field names. I tried hiding the company name I work for and think I altered the code too much. I put it closer to what it actually is. Pretty much, the column is called "COM_CONTRACT_CODE", not just "CONTRACT_CODE"

Comment: I have also tried the code below. Doesn't throw an error but also doesn't return anything:
`WHERE a.contract.contractCode = ?`

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work. I had to change the `<many-to-one>` section to the following:

```
<property name="comContractCode" type="string">
    <meta attribute="scope-field">@Length(min = 0, max = 15) private</meta>
    <column name="COM_CONTRACT_CODE" length="15"/>
</property>
<many-to-one name="contract" column="COM_CONTRACT_CODE" class="Contract" insert="false" update="false" />
```